# Read serial id mifare with pyscard

Tags: python, ubuntu, mifare

I am trying everything to read a serial id with a mifare card. 
I can use the atr from pyscard. But he will give the same id when i am using mulitiple cards.

Or do i write data on a mifare card. But how can i do this. I am useing the python script on a ubuntu server. My cardreader is a acr122u.

Please it will be very helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use is [pyscard](http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/) (Python module) or [Java Smart Card I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html) (part of Java JDK)

Answer (score 5):

You should use APDU commands for this to work.
The command to get UID is 0xFF,0xCA,0x00,0x00,0x00 in case of a mifare card.

Follow [this link](http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.nl/2010/04/pcsc-sample-in-python.html?m=1) and look under high level api. This should give you an idea.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some quick and dirty python code that uses [pyscard](http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/) and prints the UID (with assertions in lieu of actual error handling) by sending the APDU from [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19394226/195061).

```
from smartcard.scard import *

hresult, hcontext = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER)

assert hresult==SCARD_S_SUCCESS

hresult, readers = SCardListReaders(hcontext, [])

assert len(readers)>0

reader = readers[0]

hresult, hcard, dwActiveProtocol = SCardConnect(
    hcontext,
    reader,
    SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
    SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1)

hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard,dwActiveProtocol,[0xFF,0xCA,0x00,0x00,0x00])

print(response)
```